# Rails ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have problems solving the following error when running the app on Heroku, after a deploying recently:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Occurs when: signing in / signing out and submitting forms, error messages are raised about 75% of the time.

It has something to do with csrf/authenticity tokens, however everything used to work fine, and in development there are no problems.

the <%= csrf_meta_tags %> and authenticity_tokens are included in the forms.

How can this suddenly happen?

heroku logs

```
 2014-03-22T12:19:27.996333+00:00 app[web.2]:   bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996335+00:00 app[web.2]:   bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996354+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/ca
llbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996360+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/noti
fications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996368+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/ba
se.rb:136:in `process'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996336+00:00 app[web.2]:
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996362+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/noti
fications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996378+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routin
g/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996355+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996337+00:00 app[web.2]:
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996283+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/cach
e/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996277+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:
in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996341+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/request_forgery_protection.
rb:163:in `handle_unverified_request'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996239+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in
 `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996275+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagg
ed_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996363+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996399+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996338+00:00 app[web.2]:
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996357+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996384+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journe
y/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996297+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pr
e_process'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996344+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/request_forgery_protection.rb:170:in `handle_unverified_request'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996251+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/query_
cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996280+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in
 `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996387+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996340+00:00 app[web.2]: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthen
ticityToken):
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996365+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996358+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/noti
fications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996400+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/query_
cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996305+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in
`start'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996294+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `bl
ock in pre_process'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996349+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/request_forgery_protection.rb:177:in `verify_authenticity_token'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996268+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996292+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in
 `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996403+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996410+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996411+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996372+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/re
ndering.rb:44:in `process'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996376+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996418+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagg
ed_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996422+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:
in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996391+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996402+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996423+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996435+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:97:
in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996432+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996437+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in
 `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996394+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:
225:in `context'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996412+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996450+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `
run'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996445+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:
in `run_machine'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996446+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:
in `run'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996397+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:
220:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996449+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start
'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996453+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb
:84:in `start'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996463+00:00 app[web.2]:
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996452+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start
'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996414+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996274+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagg
ed_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996459+00:00 app[web.2]:   bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996457+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in
`<top (required)>'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996425+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in
 `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996303+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:
in `run'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996366+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railti
es/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996375+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996351+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/call
backs.rb:377:in `_run__3606036784356827589__process_action__callbacks'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996448+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in
`start'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996290+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:97:
in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996307+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start
'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996373+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/meta
l.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996382+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journe
y/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996352+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/call
backs.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996302+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:
in `run_machine'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996308+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `
run'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996404+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/call
backs.rb:373:in `_run__2997722282201691042__call__callbacks'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996419+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagg
ed_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996381+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routin
g/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996386+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routin
g/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996434+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `
call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996444+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `re
ceive_data'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996379+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routin
g/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996405+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/call
backs.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996383+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journe
y/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996388+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in
 `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996390+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996462+00:00 app[web.2]:
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996421+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagg
ed_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996415+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:
in `call_app'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996417+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:
in `block in call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996393+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996429+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middle
ware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996431+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `cal
l'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996442+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `pr
ocess'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996427+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'

2014-03-22T12:19:27.996438+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `bl
ock in pre_process'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996454+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in
`block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996428+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/cach
e/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996439+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `ca
tch'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996456+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in
`tap'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996441+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pr
e_process'
2014-03-22T12:19:27.996460+00:00 app[web.2]:   bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

It was solved for me by turning on Full SSL on Cloudflare.

Comment: Any idea why could this help?

Comment: Because my cookies were set to secure context and with HTTP they were not stored

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly without more information, but here's my guess: check your caching implementation.

If the pages that are throwing errors are ones that are being cached, and your authenticity token has changed, they may have an old authenticity token that's cached for their submit forms etc, which obviously won't match the newer token.

This would explain why it's working fine locally (where you probably aren't caching), as well as why it's not failing every time (if not every page is being cached).

(Oh, and unrelated comment - please update your rails version. 4.0.3 had some important security fixes in it)

Comment: I have not yet implemented anything caching related, I also added the logs from heroku.

Comment: removing the line protect_from_forgery solves the problem, but this is not a permanent solution ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve the problem, even though I'm not sure why..

```
protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session
```